# VBA entering debugging when startup code is executed?

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

I have some code in:

```
Workbook_Open()
```

And it misbehave.
(I remove all VBA modules and then import them, and "removed" modules stay long enough to interfere with importing...)

How to debug such code?

Comment: I've never tried, but couldn't you rename the modules before removing them, to make sure they don't interfere with the new ones?

Comment: It should not help, as Excel stops at compilation error due to enumerate type declaration appearing twice, and this new file already have different name. :|

Comment: It seam to be some hairy VBA behavior where it leave old modules as they are needed as dependencies for already compiled modules...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can debug your `Workbook_Open` by placing a `Stop` command before the first line of code, save and close the workbook then re-open it and step through the code using `F8`.

Comment: Funny enough I added it at savecode (that is executed on save)... and it made Excel import new code (and execute it properly...), even though all modules names where wrong. But "Stop" is exactly what I looked for! Thx!

Comment: `Stop` works only if your VBA project isn't password protected

Comment: @datenstation If you were **developing a workbook** why would you have the VBA project password protected?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald You maybe want to debug your code executed when you open your workbook. In this case you have to completely remove password protection of the VBA project to get `Stop` working.

Comment: Stop command worked for me also. Thanks!